# Trying to find find or design 2x20 GPIO header in altium

Tags: fpga, altium, gpio, ribbon-cable

For my project i am using DE1 Soc development board.

I am trying to connect a camera to it using the ribbon

Camera has the output of Semtec Connector, and I need to connect the 40pins from semtec to the pins of a female 2x20 header. The Semtec connector specifications I have already as I am only modifying an altium project file which has been made prior by someone else to connect the same camera but to a different FPGA.

I can not find within altium any header which resembles the one I need. I can fin headers for any multiple of 2 besides the 40/2x20 one, let alone having the same pin spacing.

I can not find anywhere within the DE1 Soc datasheets any info about the headers, such as the width of the pins, total length or the manufacturer's number.

If someone could suggest to me how to find the 2x20 female header as I am sure it exists somewhere already or how can I find the exact measurements of the connector that is on the FPGA so that I can design the holes myself.

Thank you.

Comment: It's just a 0.1" header, right? If you're going to use altium, you need to get used to making your own components.

Comment: That's the thing I never use altium, last time I used it was years ago. Thanks for that dimension I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ALWAYS recommend creating your own libraries when working within Altium. Using third-party or built-in libraries leads to mismatch in styles that can be confusing to you or to your viewers. It also allows you to create custom parts that may not already exist in libraries, as I expect may be your case. I created a tutorial on how to make your own libraries in Altium Designer. You can find the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kyY25CGJtM

The video walks you through how to start your own library and how to use the manufacturer's datasheet/part drawings to generate your own symbols and footprints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the two 2x20 pin headers on [this board](https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=836), they are 2x20 100-mil male pin headers, very common.

IIRC Altium does in fact have footprints for the mating connector for these. However, if you can't find them, *build your own*. Creating your own footprints is an expected process when designing a board.